# Where can I store an array that changes per row in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel as well as PHP in general. The following code is working, but I want to be able to change the way the xml data parses into the array depending on the id that is passed in to the parseXML function.

```
<?php namespace Podguest\Feed;

use Podguest\Feed\TimeFormat;

class FeedConnect {

    public function fetch($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $this->xml = new \SimpleXMLElement ($output);

        return $this->xml;

    }

    public function parseXML($xml, $id)
    {
        $data = [];
        $i = 0;

            foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
            $namespace = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
            $itunes = $item->children($namespace['itunes']);

            $data[$i++] = [
                'number' => preg_replace('/^.*#|\s-.*/', '', (string)$item->title),
                'title' => (string)$item->title,
                'pub_date' => date_format(date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s O', (string)$item->pubDate),'m/d/Y'),
                'duration' => TimeFormat::convertSeconds((string)$itunes->duration),
                'description' => (string)$item->description,
                'guests' => preg_replace('/^.* - |,? &.*|, \bme\b/i', '', (string)$item->title),
                'url' => (string)$item->link

            ];
    }   

        return $this->data = $data;
    }

}
```

I have no clue what the best way to do this is. I wanted to store them in the mySQL database, but that is not a good idea from what I've read about eval(). What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: changing the function to answer what was asked in the comments

You can extract the formatting portion of this function into a new one and decide how you need the XML to be formatted before calling that function. I've added a boolean parameter that need to be true when you're formatting your special XML.

WARNING: untested code follows...

```
public function parseXML($xml, $id, $specialXML = false)
{

    $i = 0;
    $data = [];

    foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
    {
        $namespace = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
        $itunes = $item->children($namespace['itunes']);

        if($specialXML == true)
        {
            $data[$i][] = $this->XMLToArrayFormatter($item);
        } else {
            $data[][$i++] = $this->XMLToArrayFormatter($item);
        }

     }   

      return $this->data = $data;
}

protected function XMLToArrayFormatter()
{
            return [
                'number' => preg_replace('/^.*#|\s-.*/', '', (string)$item->title),
                'title' => (string)$item->title,
                'pub_date' => date_format(date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s O', (string)$item->pubDate),'m/d/Y'),
                'duration' => TimeFormat::convertSeconds((string)$itunes->duration),
                'description' => (string)$item->description,
                'guests' => preg_replace('/^.* - |,? &.*|, \bme\b/i', '', (string)$item->title),
                'url' => (string)$item->link

            ];
 }
```

Comment: How can I make it so the key -> values for the array are not hard coded in this file though? Those values work for 1 specific xml file (which is pulled from the database) but won't give me the desired results from the next xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multidimensional array in PHP:

```
$this->data[$id][$i++] = ...
```

Every $id will have its own list of items. And you should store it in your $data property.

So your code could look like:

```
<?php namespace Podguest\Feed;

use Podguest\Feed\TimeFormat;

class FeedConnect {

    protected $data = [];

    public function fetch($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $this->xml = new \SimpleXMLElement ($output);

        return $this->xml;

    }

    public function parseXML($xml, $id)
    {
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) 
        {
            $namespace = $item->getNameSpaces(true);

            $itunes = $item->children($namespace['itunes']);

            $this->data[$id][$i++] = [
                'number' => preg_replace('/^.*#|\s-.*/', '', (string)$item->title),
                'title' => (string)$item->title,
                'pub_date' => date_format(date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s O', (string)$item->pubDate),'m/d/Y'),
                'duration' => TimeFormat::convertSeconds((string)$itunes->duration),
                'description' => (string)$item->description,
                'guests' => preg_replace('/^.* - |,? &.*|, \bme\b/i', '', (string)$item->title),
                'url' => (string)$item->link

            ];
        }   

        return $this->data;
    }

}
```